# I can download folder with aws cli but cannot download folder with aws sdk

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-sdk, aws-cli

I follow this guide https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/examples-s3-transfermanager.html#tranfermanager-download-directoryand create program download directory from s3 to local.

So, a folder i can download with cli but cannot download with sdk.

this is my code download dir with aws sdk:

```java
TransferManager tm = TransferManagerBuilder.standard().withS3Client(getAmazonS3()).build();
        try {
            MultipleFileDownload xfer = tm.downloadDirectory(bucketName, keyName, new File(localPath));
            xfer.waitForCompletion();
        } catch (AmazonServiceException e) {
            log.error("Amazon service error: " + e.getMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        } catch (AmazonClientException e) {
            log.error("Amazon client error: " + e.getMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            log.error("Transfer interrupted: " + e.getMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
```

Comment: "Cannot" means what? Errors? Explosions?

Comment: I think it download all folder, but each file in folder not download and program hangs there